# Sticky Notes on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have trouble running Sticky Notes on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit), In fact I did that before but I have lost the installation procedure that I have made and I can not find it on the web maybe because Windows 2008 R2 is outdated now.

I have followed [this procedure](http://www.techflute.com/how-to-add-sticky-notes-to-windows-server-2012/) which is for Windows 2012 but it did not work on Windows 2008 and maybe some registry tweak is required (I don't know)

any pointer is appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here: https://www.renevdlinden.nl/2014/07/02/sticky-notes-on-windows-2008-r2/

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it [would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @anonim, the same thing actually happened to me (I could not make Sticky Notes work on Svr 2k8 R2 following instructions for Svr 2012 R2). I ended up installing this other program and it's working well: http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/

Comment: @SamAndrew81, thanks for your answer but the link is broken

Comment: I would just use a 3rd party program. This one is working well for us: www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/